# How to write a type for a method that returns a value from an array of keys, where the data are nested objects with primitive values and classes

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to write type for `getIn` method (`GetInResult`)?
I want the `result` to point to the `string` type from the `Second.second` interface of the `e2` `Example` class.

```js
type DataValue = undefined | null | boolean | string | number | bigint |  Example<any>;

// DataType can be object or array with primitive values or Example instances
interface DataType {
    [key: PropertyKey]: DataValue;
}


type Keys = readonly PropertyKey[];
type GetInResult<T, KS extends Keys> = KS extends [infer F, ...infer R]
  ? F extends keyof T
    ? R extends Keys
      ? T[F] extends Example<infer NestedT>
        ? NestedT extends DataType 
          ? GetInResult<NestedT, R> 
          : undefined
        : T[F]
      : T[F]
    : undefined
  : undefined;

class Example<T extends DataType> {
    #data: T;
    constructor(data: T){
        this.#data = data;
    }

    getIn<KS extends Keys, K extends PropertyKey>(keys: KS & K[]): GetInResult<T, KS> {
    const key = keys.shift();
    if (key && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.#data,key)) {
      const value = this.#data[key];
      if (keys.length) {
        if (value instanceof Example) {
          return value.getIn(keys);
        }
        return undefined;
      }
      return value; // error: check playground below
    }
    return undefined;
  }
}

interface Second extends DataType {
    second: string;
}

const second: Second = {
    second: '2'
}

const e2 = new Example(second);


interface First extends DataType {
    first: string;
    firstNested: Example<Second>;
}


const first: First = {
    first:'1',
    firstNested: e2
};

const e1 = new Example(first);

const result = e1.getIn(['firstNested','second']);
// result should be a string from Second.second interface because firstNested is pointing to the Example<Second> and second points to Second.second
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=100&ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOA1OAbArtAvFdA7AEwgDMBLPCAqAHyj3VVRqgCMB7N1COPZgZ2AAncgHNm9ALYsIg5i1IjywZlACiADzgSwXADw8QAPgDcAKFMB6C7ARwAKuGgBjHq2hsWAKwhPlbWXCCgnAgUADupMAAFlBgwhKRpABu0ElomHxQ-mqa2lxQ5AI8ThB8pkoyxHAlNogOkFAA3qZQrVAA2gDWECAAXFAACoJskIKgANI9ALr98IgoGBBmAL7mpqANkyCZOILcBGx4qKFDIzITPe1TZhvQAOIQwACSeABKpQzAunYANFDjAGUoBB1MAIIRMls+IYoDhAcDQeCCJl2uRiDIoAAxP4AOjxaIxrymLSgAH4sQiwRCoN0QGxiFA7CTWuTXpSkZCemU2m1yXZ2pipuzqRotDoILoCbIAHKlMEEOyGZk8slQWUCSh2YXI2r2RxQZUq1UPZ5vD6oL7q+W-KCvGGGlX9fBEMgUAgO1r9fmCh1egXEnlOwgkciUElBl2hghmUxOVBwPiZUV5CVakFUnVzPWQGHNHkAYgIti9Zh5TkOAkE6F8-gAFEXEF6AJR5o1QaKkPg4wu2WFQBtwUttVbKkSPF66eHpjn-Ll-cbazKnUYXIy12l8frwgBk-yuTf6Jpe7z4n2+84BueV5bwAhpPT7G5xfCipGIwFrTaHrTfUHXD+3XcAHkvB8YAcTiNhgCgxwcSiBMgLCPBl3OEAcRcRhaw7Lse0QH5aSbJsmgdG87zSRY+2w7sBy6aZvzaX9-22HEuDwERoiI1sjUY8jMAKW9EDwEp6RyMUuE4j02j2YB0EEXheIgHEx1NJi+C-STVjbKBpNk3hnRDN16NaTSVR0uSoAU4wDR5EzWjMvTg1dSgh1WEcKkEKoagBHxDioadqSzepoC4qA+B8wh+krUQVnMUjlDCm8CH6bzEr7EKEt8-oAHIACYstMEc4uBHK+woMJRJTWsMsIdTzHczzoExUhBDvfzM1sILiJ5MgWuASKhGi5UeoEK1KH6ZNxV0FLfJMAq1iK4a+qxZq7xwELFt6LKAEYsp+IaVuAUakuKgqYyKiAttKiByomrha0W2qir2U8LT7C6lPHPBa3aLLFqO3asuqggsqmdSrG0814qiNgGCoaQoDgUKBrYqBiGGCQoGmwhn3Cqh6uqaBpBcdAwtRg6joKTIwDYJRRHbNh2yiaBbolLGCBhHgqCB2IabwYBMmgzHcZxxKgA)

Comment: For this to be a [mre] you should describe exactly what the problem is in detail (if there is an error in your existing code, what is the error and where does it occur?) and what the intent is (what types do you expect to see in your usage examples?  Do you have an expectation for the type of `result`?  If so, what is it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made modifications to [@myNameIsDu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16687742/mynameisdu) code and was able to achieve a satisfactory result.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=100&ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOA1OAbArtAvAKClAHynQDsATCAMwEsSIy9CoT1VVGiAjAe29QjgkOUAM7AATrQDmwlgFtOEccM7UptYMICiADzhyw-ADyCQAPgDcOHKEiwEcACrgIAeU4ArCAGNgULFAA3owA2gAKAFxQYeLckOKgANIQIAC6UfCIKBgQVgC+VjYu9ojOkACC4uJwIEaOUBA6wBDkIiXIaJhm-lCV1bWOlta20ADiEMAAkiRlEHUNTS1kbeICZNwkqCDEJADWJNwA7iQhqQA0sN0B9Y3NrVCrcOub2yG0lEpQADIXAHT-70+AE1UowAPzfBZ3ZZQXYpbiUWCMfAQmAhL6pKFLNq6fSGOaA8RQAByEDE9EyThcZmR+CgEKBIQA5PwSFJgAALJmY27YqAABnpsHRmKIpAoNDoZCgUXGUxmLiMQIupPJZEpsxpdLpUUZLJa7K5PMW935tO1qJF5p1OwltHotKi4qo9oY+CijmZrMN3KxpqgtIhdAAbkpHVBPfzjdC2nCQAjYAHtSjhZHUqDkzLbS6pYUNEpKHBvNBJriDMYbiaYRqXO4vL4mDWKlUaiYSOZusF8FIJtMjIk-TDHs8ttFYvEkilTmYABRxkRRRIASllvYVkH7F0G+Ws3lQcBEOL05bmlZj7VmdZ8fiITYgfVbpjM3WoJ7kLWAbVLx-xdTMXagABiMgHA9Kx8G8DYxHEdBfG4cQZxAxAPSXIJaU5agRF+YCHB6JC4HAqA8msbs137QcVjWDZRxiOIlEnEBpznFIFygZdV3lWZNwjTtaUgkgxGYCBDmSEA2gCEJ-l+edUkIiCoL8OMejoESWN+EQOWoShgBnJc5KgLSoGY7YADITKgK9fF+MBYmAbgRl+DkD1cY5aInEBfm8NBUBnDCsJwxALjjJdUIA7UAHpwqgAABT8AFo1AOVZrX4wTg06bAoD87D8JCONZOtQyZxU0SsO9TlQutfAivSnIDIExASGLBMy3xSrM21VZgHQcQSCgWrMF+Ht5WK4TStQg8oFMfTtWIjqHgmHq+udSV6CmtpputObky6pb+oy9apvbfTtvwXbeuzVbpUmzb8GI4iijsRxNPEMgH22AI73eoxoOkIYcFSvwMNej0XrelsPqgZlmjEJkziZGHgAAJl9SbSH2I4+sm57qFe97CkBhoAGZlOEqBWv4Xywb04ZigAZR8DZpQCACREZ8gol+tlCLZ-iyGJdAFCUKJ5EUcRCOBsgogp08wfeoYCl3BTRHZqWoAZvmelZ1WoiZFGzkYXmmYFoXxCiJGDfwSWoggImDcVgHlYgJHScOcmf0po3yBpx7oAAMVxwSWcYGhxDETmJGkQjQ7EVVmjVmWjA1pmFYJ5WY+AKIA7Dvxg-wDPdYARjhkPA+AOP6Bti2cAdx2GoaQvXfdvFKYzn3CfnHpmQziuyDhqAmS9vvMUmwGrEJ1YRFYXOG6GtdjJEGmJ7JaeXYCCBC7nkbu7L3u4cH1XUbaQGl+Vyfp5J9fN+G6YZx3nO9-hoeTbFo+oBP8ez5X1BgAAFh6DeW9b731jmSeO+8DjADio0TCn434fzroJc+P8ACsADr7zxAeXMB9B96S37lGQ6CDl5Tx-gANnQUAkgd8mQ9xwcPIhClT712QcAAA7D0VhZCwRUJoUPeBTDP4sO-sAAAHJQm+1CsGPwRmDARDVmFIJEQATk4SI0RPDJF30IaPQRu59yHmbieJG8xeT3DvJZG8F4XDfSfN0MxMJE6DAMm+D8X4nH-gevmcQhZixQEmM0OQFFrGQEsWhaqasuZSEIvuRQqAI6SG5jXaw3jfHQAAEpHDaA4toFjPDXnCVDOMUQ3L0RAKJdIRj8QmICRAOQCslb12oIEwu-JKRRFqUEvOBkpZMmaXUuKrSS74FiRAeJfTAlQCGTXNOTSWmCgCCpKp-AkYzn6XIVplJ25nyye0zJhxxJBAmQMoZER1mtIdhPLJTcZarNiAcrZQjBLrM4Vk3hzJ1mDJEPyeRYg9JAA)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=100&ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOA1OAbArtAvAKClAHynQDsATCAMwEsSIy9CoT1VVGiAjAe29QjgkOUAM7AATrQDmwlgFtOEccM7UptYMICiADzhyw-ADyCQAPgDcOHKEiwEcACrhsUAN6MA2gAUAXFG9xbkhxUABpCBAAXX94RBQMCCsAXysAY1Q4EREoXX1DCCNHKAgdYAhyHLinFzN3RjIHf0crfDTuEjFxdDTgbnEACkbEZoBKevx8YAALahEAOmG4KCwoJdaoZOt8KQhgAEkSIzCSsoqyHPEBMg7UEFEJaU8oswGAa0iRfzDR-wBxPaHZyQY4AGigjjqHkmUHanWAzAgAHcIiAcqtPPMsR80VENm0OmIoDiVoiUZ95iJZpRgANRvioNRKFB3pEoAAydlQADynAAVhBevMwEE+rYIPNplluUiSIFgkpQPM0mhUAMZnNFg5wTjRuNoTDYYSEQA3NCYUkahZLTw4vGMGFMlk4hb8EhSGb6h2Gp0DM2JRnwwRpCDcZl5Az8L2Gw1XYDocQkKD+zDzXYHEgDOjktH070wrYx-BxhNJ0gUGh0MhQLI1kggBn4Quxval5Pm6C10wM5vF1uJ4jkKi0eg1nLdxhbLY2FxQADKgo61dWBpEi-I-i60hSVhwcKJa7hZH8C6PpNX6+PUAA5AAma+gnCpaz7hEQW+k7O5PSRiADQ9LnmM52AAYtQ4hEiujA0BBwCbo87obDBYgAHIQGI9D+BGBRGKeS6WE+u6vlAyFwVAYGwee0HgWI-jXgAjA+1GwWhGFXu+j7PuKUAAhmwKFMUpTlJUUBXHANwkHcg5vCQ3Cys84IwHUqyCWcIliRJUmeIwtCUEoUAADKPvgWLzLp+kAJqPlEjAAPyGacwkXMSkRhrA3r2TAngGVEjnnDk2HGKYZj5lA9m8UCLhGFZsDeVEnjXks14vKF-gWQlboetMyV+SJAAMoWeXFqWDhWI4MDC-h0CaSiMFVEA1eIRHGiU9Gfsi375PwAykUB3EAIKkhFJD8UYCWkax5RkA+N4AeQyXghRYgEXuLUuqS400cAk30DN15zdNvm1q+zXwqJ6GsAiqwQPRaaApmLr0kAA)

The difference is that data is not private and requires `const assertions`

Comment: Thanks for this example. These combinations with const keys are not very cool as far as the end user is concerned but somehow it could be handled, unfortunately the data has to be private.